# In Java, how can I fail if my program is run without -ea?

Tags: java, assertions

Is there a way to check if the program was started with `-ea` so that I can exit/fail if it wasn't?  If an assertion fails, I want to be informed about it.  Therefore, I consider it a critical error to start up without this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make an assertion guaranteed to fail.

If code after that assertion runs, assertions weren't enabled.

```
boolean asserted = false;

try {
   assert false;
} catch (AssertionError e) {
   asserted = true;
}

if (!asserted) {
    System.err.println("Missing '-ea' flag; exiting.");
    System.exit(1);
    // ... or throw a RuntimeException, depending on your environment.
}
```

---

That said, I'm not 100% convinced forcing assertions is a great idea. IMO assertions are more for development rather than normal error checking/handling.

Comment: I only meant to illustrate, I have no argument with your current version.

Comment: But -1 is a really bad idea, since the official exit code space is 0 - 255, unsigned :-)

Comment: @bmargulies *lolgrr* That one was actually a typo--still over-eager :/

Comment: Not a good idea to actually throw an error, which is unnecessary.

Comment: @DavidConrad I don't see any code throwing an error (although the code added to my answer via an edit did use the wrong error). I tend towards your solution; my original answer did not have an answer with code in it, since it seemed obvious without it.

Comment: @DaveNewton I was referring to the line `assert false;` which will throw an AssertionError.

Comment: @DavidConrad Right; having an error thrown there is up to the JVM, not the user. Maybe you meant it's not necessary to explicitly catch it, although IMO it doesn't make a lot of difference.

Comment: @DaveNewton I guess it doesn't make a lot of difference to performance, but there's no need to have any throwing, catching, or try blocks to solve this problem.

Comment: @DavidConrad And I agree, but saying there's "no throwing necessary" is misleading, since that exception will be thrown if assertions are on. It's not user code throwing the AssertionError.

Comment: @DaveNewton It relies on the fact that the user code `assert false;` will result in an `AssertionError` being thrown. I don't see any meaningful difference here; you do. Okay.

Answer (score 4):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    boolean ok = true;
    try {
        assert false;
        ok = false;
    } catch (AssertionError ex) {
    }
    if (!ok) {
        System.err.println("FATAL: assertions are not enabled.\n");
        System.exit(1);
    }
}
```

Comment: How does this work? There's no throw if -ea is missing. Isn't this precisely backwards?

Comment: Isn't this backwards?  This will error when assertions *are* enabled.

Comment: You are both right in that it used to be backwards. It is, however, fixed now.

Comment: There's no need for an actual Error to be thrown.

Answer (score 1):

This is the rare case when you actually want to have an assertion with side effects, which is normally a big no-no.

```
public class MustAssert {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        boolean exit = true;
        assert (exit = false) == false;
        if (exit) {
            System.out.println("You forgot to turn assertions on with -ea.");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        process(args);
    }

    public static void process(String[] args) {
        // The rest of your program, whatever it may be, goes here.
        for (String s : args) System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

The boolean flag is initially true, indicating that we should bail out. The assertion, if it is evaluated, is a tautology. The variable is set to false, the value of that sub-expression is false, which is then compared to false, and since `false == false` evaluates to true, the assertion passes and no `AssertionError` is thrown. The flag is set to false as a side effect of evaluating the assertion.

If assertions are turned off, the expression is never evaluated, and the flag retains its initial value of true. We then bail out with a warning that assertions are turned off.

I think using an assertion with side effects, although normally frowned upon, is better and cleaner when attempting to detect whether assertions are turned on than throwing and catching AssertionError.

Comment: I think this is a pretty good answer, but I think my IDE would mark this as a warning (for all I know the other ones would too, I haven't tested them yet).  That's my biggest concern.  Is there a way to ignore this warning?

Comment: What IDE, and what warning is it producing? I'm using Eclipse 4.2.1 and I don't get any warnings. I have the 'Possible accidental boolean assignment' warning turned on in the compiler options, which I think is the most likely one it would trip.